# Mass calculate between dataframes and create new column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have two dataframes (df1 and df2) with analogous metrics (MetricA/MetricA1 and MetricB/MetricB1). I want to calculate the delta between them in a third column in df1 (as shown conceptually in df3). What is the best way to do that without having to type each calc individually? Reprex below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df1=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(15, 2)), columns=['MetricA', 'MetricB'])
df2=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(15, 2)), columns=['MetricA1', 'MetricB1'])
df3=df2=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(15, 4)), columns=['MetricA', 'MetricB','DeltaMetricAAndA1', 'DeltaMetricBAndB1'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a join:

```
df3 = df1.join(df1.sub(df2.values).add_prefix("Delta"))
```

Output:

```
    MetricA  MetricB  DeltaMetricA  DeltaMetricB
0        17       42           -49           -29
1        20       48           -33           -21
2        22       13           -14            -8
3        97       53            57           -24
4        84       10            -7           -39
5        96       55            49           -22
6        61       56            21           -22
7        89       21            44           -66
8        96       83            80            55
9        25       14           -20           -53
10       13       84           -53             6
11       43        6            -3             6
12       77       56            48            -7
13       59       15           -16           -20
14       24        9           -29           -84
```